# how i can open time picker dialog box in dynamic layout

Tags: android, timepicker

I have three Edit text 
1)is for service
2)is for charges 
3)is for time
so i don't know how many service a beauty saloon is given .so I make a dynamic layout where the service provider choose there service dynamically .I'm using two layout One is parent layout and second is child view Layout ..all work is good but when it pick the time. the time picker dialog box  open only in parent layout .it cant open in child view layout ..if some one know please help me ..here is my complete code and picture

> childview.xml

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/service"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:hint="@string/edittext_service"
        android:inputType="text"/>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/charges"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:hint="@string/edittext_charge"
        android:inputType="number"/>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/time"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:hint="@string/edittext_time"

        android:inputType="number"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Sub"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:drawable/ic_delete"
        android:onClick="onDelete"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

> ServicesAndRateList.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="false">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:id="@+id/parent_linear_layout"
        tools:context=".ServicesAndRateList">

        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/service"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:hint="@string/edittext_service"
                android:inputType="text"/>
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/charges"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:hint="@string/edittext_charge"
                android:inputType="number"/>
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/time"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:hint="@string/edittext_time"

                android:inputType="number"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Sub"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="INSERT"
                android:background="@android:drawable/ic_delete"
                />


        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/add"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ripple"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:onClick="onAddField"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:text="Add Field"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/submit"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ripple"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:onClick="INSERT"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:text="Register"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"/>


        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

> ServicesAndRateList.java

```
public class ServicesAndRateList extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText service, charge, time;
TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog;
private LinearLayout parentLinearLayout;
private Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_services_and_rate_list);

    parentLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.parent_linear_layout);

    time = findViewById(R.id.time);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            for (int i = 0; i < parentLinearLayout.getChildCount() - 1; i++) {
                service = (EditText) (parentLinearLayout.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.service));
                charge = (EditText) (parentLinearLayout.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.charges));
                time = (EditText) (parentLinearLayout.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.time));

                String Service = service.getText().toString();
                String Charge = charge.getText().toString();
                String Time = time.getText().toString();

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(Service)) {
                    service.requestFocus();
                } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(Charge)) {
                    charge.requestFocus();
                } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(Time)) {
                    time.requestFocus();
                }
            }
        }
    });


    time.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(ServicesAndRateList.this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int hourOfDay, int minutes) {

                    time.setText(hourOfDay + ":" + minutes);

                }
            }, 0, 0, true);

            timePickerDialog.show();
        }
    });

}


public void onDelete(View view) {
    parentLinearLayout.removeView((View) view.getParent());
}

public void onAddField(View view) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    final View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.childview, null);
    // Add the new row before the add field button.
    parentLinearLayout.addView(rowView, parentLinearLayout.getChildCount() - 1);

}
```

}

> picture of my xml

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you setting `View.ClickListener` only to a single view `EditText time` that is a direct child of `R.layout.activity_services_and_rate_list`.

Later you add more child views to inflated `R.layout.activity_services_and_rate_list` layout but not setting click listeners.

One of the options would be to create a method that will set click listener for each passed in time `EditText`.

*Note: Consider using `RecyclerView` with Adapter. It has much better performance when the number of views grows in your layout.*

```
public class ServicesAndRateList extends AppCompatActivity {

    //your variables here ...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //your other onCreate code here ...

        setTimeEditTextClickListener(time);
    }

    private void setTimeEditTextClickListener(EditText time) {
        time.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(ServicesAndRateList.this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int hourOfDay, int minutes) {
                        time.setText(hourOfDay + ":" + minutes);
                    }
                }, 0, 0, true);

                timePickerDialog.show();
            }
        });
    }

    public void onAddField(View view) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.childview, null);
        // Add the new row before the add field button.
        parentLinearLayout.addView(rowView, parentLinearLayout.getChildCount() - 1);
        setTimeEditTextClickListener((EditText) rowView.findViewById(R.id.time));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much .. it work  perfectly ... thank you soo soo much for your effort  and being so quick

Comment: @benten, you are welcome. Recommend you to consider using `RecyclerView` instead of adding views one by one. It will help you a lot in future.

Comment: again thank you so much ..  I will consider your recommendation .because your are expert in this field . and I try Recyclerview